# set/change value to drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to set or change value to drop down.

I'm having a drop down list which is initially not selected a value.

How can i select a value using jquery

Answer (score 6):

The [`val()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) function is used to get and set the value of input controls (including `<select>`). Grab a jQuery reference to your `<select>`, and pass its `val()` function a string matching the `value` attribute of the `<option>` that you wish to select:

```
$("#mySelect").val("15");
```

This would select the second option in this list:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="5">Few</option>
    <option value="15">More</option>
    <option value="100">Many</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id_select").val("value_1");
```

id_select -> is the id of your select

value_1 -> is one of the values presents in the option of select